# Use vectors of a list as index for vectors of another list

Tags: r, indexing

I have two lists, each of them containing the same number of vectors. List1 contains vectors all of the same length, while List2 contains vectors of possibly different lenghths. The idea is, to use the content of the vectors of List2 as indices for the corresponding vectors of List1.

Here is some code for an reproducible example:

```
# create empty lists
List1 <- list()
List2 <- list()


# fill the lists with vectors
set.seed(50)
for (i in 1:1000) {
  List1[[i]] <- sample(0:500, 360, replace= T)
}

set.seed(100)
for (i in 1:1000) {
  List2[[i]] <- sample(0:200, 50, replace= T)
}
```

Here an example of what I wish to do with extracting a vector from each list:

```
vec1 <- List1[[1]]
vec2 <- List2[[1]]

# now use the second vector as index for the first one
vec1[vec2]
```

The question is now, how to transfer this to the entire lists, so that the output is again a list with the resulting vectors?

Anybody with an idea?

**EDIT:**
This is an edit after some very helpful answers with a new structure of lists, the question remains the same.

Here is the code for an reproducible example:

```
# create empty lists
List1 <- list()
List2 <- list()


# fill the lists with vectors
set.seed(50)
for (i in 1:1000) {
  List1[[i]] <- sample(0:500, 360, replace= T)
}

set.seed(100)
for (i in 1:1000) {
  List2[[i]] <- sample(0:200, 50, replace= T)
}

# create the first level sublists
sublist1 <- list()
sublist2 <- list()
for (i in 1:8) {
  sublist1[[i]] <- List1
  sublist2[[i]] <- List2
}

# create the super lists
superlist1 <- list(sublist1, sublist1, sublist1, sublist1, sublist1, sublist1, sublist1, sublist1)
superlist2 <- list(sublist2, sublist2, sublist2, sublist2, sublist2, sublist2, sublist2, sublist2)
```

As you can see, the two superlists have the same structure, they only differ in the lengths of the lists of the lowest levels.

So now the question is, how to use the values of `superlist2[[1]][[1]][[1]]` as vectors for the corresponding element in `superlist1`, which is `superlist1[[1]][[1]][[1]]` and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `Map` in `base R`

```
Map(`[`, List1, List2)
```

Answer (score 6):

You need an `apply`-function:

```r
lapply(seq_along(List1), function(n) List1[[n]][List2[[n]]])
```

returns the expected list.

With `tidyverse` you could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

List1 %>% 
  map2(.y = List2, ~.x[.y])
```

to get the same result.

Comment: Thanks Martin Gal, this works perfectly fine! In fact, my two lists are both sublists of bigger lists. Do you know how to nest the command, when the relevant lists are on the third level (means lists of lists of lists)?

Comment: This depends on the actual structure of your lists. Do you have an example?

Comment: Martin Gal sorry for the late reply, I was on holidays. I have edited the question above, so that you can reproduce the structure of my lists.

Comment: I'm on vacation now. Perhaps it's better to create a new question?

Answer (score 3):

This is my first loop. so it is a try, please be kind:

```
# loop
for (i in 1:length(List1)) {
    print(List1[[i]][List2[[i]]])
}
```